# Why is my WordPress PHP header template generating oddly coded paths and transcluding some css and js file in the outputted HTML?

Tags: php, html, wordpress, encoding

I think this is an encoding problem(?), but not really sure.

When I view my generated source (in both FF and IE) I see funky paths from my js and css files like: `<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.domain.com/wp-content/themes/dudical/js/ce.f4195499d3cfc40ae09588aae02ff2dc.jquery,oeasing,omin,l.js"></script>`

Also, several of the js/css files are actually being transcluded, i.e I don't see references to the external files, but instead the content of those files are being shown in the source inside of `<script>` and `<style>` tags respectively. I've never seen this type of behavior before and am pretty baffled.

Here is how my header.php file begins:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" <?php language_attributes(); ?>>
    <head profile="http://gmpg.org/xfn/11">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="<?php bloginfo('html_type'); ?>; charset=<?php bloginfo('charset'); ?>" />
    <title><?php if (is_front_page() ) {
        bloginfo('name');
        } elseif ( is_category() ) {
            single_cat_title(); echo ' - ' ; bloginfo('name');
        } elseif (is_single() ) {
            single_post_title();
        } elseif (is_page() ) {
            single_post_title(); echo ' - '; bloginfo('name');
        } else {
            wp_title('',true);
        } ?>
    </title>
    <?php if(get_option('favicon')) { ?>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="<?php echo get_option('favicon'); ?>" type="image/x-icon" /> 
    <?php }else{?><link rel="shortcut icon" href="<?php echo system32_url; ?>/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" /> <?php } ?>
    <?php if ( is_singular() ) wp_enqueue_script( 'comment-reply' ); ?>
    <?php wp_head(); ?>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/css/reset.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/style.css" />
    <!-- Jquery and Easing-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/js/jquery-1.4.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/js/jquery.easing.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/js/jquery.capSlide.js"></script>
```

Here is what I see output:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang=en lang=en>
<head profile="http://gmpg.org/xfn/11">
<meta http-equiv=Content-Type content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"/>
<title>Surf Hatteras</title>
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="http://www.surfhatteras.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/10/surf-icon.gif" type="image/x-icon"/>
<style>body                             { outline:none;}
.postoptions                    { padding:0px; padding-top:0;  }
.postoptions select,

...

</style>
<style>/* CSS for WP-Testimonials */
#sfstest-form label {
float: left;
width: 200px;
font-weight: bold;
}

...

</style>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://www.surfhatteras.com/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js?ver=1.4.2'></script>
<link rel=EditURI type="application/rsd+xml" title=RSD href="http://www.surfhatteras.com/xmlrpc.php?rsd"/>
<link rel=wlwmanifest type="application/wlwmanifest+xml" href="http://www.surfhatteras.com/wp-includes/wlwmanifest.xml"/>
<link rel=index title='Surf Hatteras' href='http://www.surfhatteras.com/'/>
<meta name=generator content="WordPress 3.0.1"/>
<style>/* http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/ */
/* v1.0 | 20080212 */

html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, font, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    outline: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    vertical-align: baseline;
    background: transparent;
}

...

</style>
<link rel=stylesheet type="text/css" href="http://www.surfhatteras.com/wp-content/themes/dudical/ce.51cd742ab6418eec6131ff2cf43b61c4.style,s.css"/>
<!-- Jquery and Easing-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.surfhatteras.com/wp-content/themes/dudical/js/ce.9e936b27d8d0e4e07ebef242d7c6e2cc.jquery-1,o4,omin,l.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">(function($) {
    $.fn.capslide = function(options) {
        var opts = $.extend({}, $.fn.capslide.defaults, options);
        return this.each(function() {
            $this = $(this);
            var o = $.meta ? $.extend({}, opts, $this.data()) : opts;

...         

})(jQuery);</script>
<link rel=stylesheet type="text/css" href="http://www.surfhatteras.com/wp-content/themes/dudical/colors/ce.d47db6d7bbcb1f0192576f60ffa27ec9.white,s.css" media=screen />
<!-- Slider CSS-->
<style>/*
    Coin Slider jQuery plugin CSS styles
    http://workshop.rs/projects/coin-slider
*/

#coin-slider    { margin-left:20px;}

...


</style>
<link rel=stylesheet type="text/css" media=screen href="http://www.surfhatteras.com/wp-content/themes/dudical/css/cc.224c1b363a793961fc7bc2e428d6ce58.nivo-slider,s+superfish,s.css">
```

Can't figure what is happening to my paths, or why some external files are getting treated as such...

**EDIT**

List of plug-ins I am using:

- Category Posts Widget
- Contact Form 7
- Contact Form 7 to DB Extension
- Get Post Image
- Get The Image
- Resize At Upload Plus
- Widgets Reloaded
- WordPress Hashcash
- WP-DBManager
- WP-Mail-SMTP
- WP Show IDs
- WP Wunderground
- (The caching plugin I was using is Quick Cache)

[Contents of my `functions.php` file](http://wordpress.pastebin.com/DK8Cs22S)

Comment: @two7s_clash: This is probably a caching plugin that combines multiple JS and CSS requests into one. I don't see it on [your live site](http://www.surfhatteras.com/) at the moment, did you disable anything?

Comment: @Jan Fabry: Haven't touched anything. I still see lines like <link rel=stylesheet type="text/css" href="http://www.surfhatteras.com/wp-content/themes/dudical/ce.e0f51bf3c11023701ef72d70ff0f26d7.style,s.css"/>

Comment: @two7s_clash: Can you add the list of plugins you use, and the contents of your theme's `functions.php` file to the question?

Comment: @Jan Fabry  - done. Lots of dependencies. Let me know what you are looking for and I can look at some of the other files.

Comment: @two7s_clash: I could not find a theme named "Dudical", is it custom made for you? It seems to be quite advanced, maybe the JS combiner is included there? You could try looking for hooks that reference `wp_print_scripts` or something similar.

Comment: @Jan Fabry - its my heavily tweaked version of "Awesome," a theme I bought. It doesn't have a JS/CSS combiner. I'll look for those hooks though...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not a big deal.
Just because you have using Goolge Page Speed extension mod.

Comment: Aha! Lol, Dreamhost support couldn't even seem to tell me that. Its effecting a php image module I'm trying to pass images to. Thanks!